# How to free "busy" c# webbrowser

Tags: javascript, c#, webbrowser-control

I am using c# and webbrowser to scrape a web page.

Sometimes, I will run into a "Message from webpage" popup error.

I use:

```
hwnd = FindWindow("#32770", "Message from webpage");
hwnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "OK");
SendMessage(hwnd, 0xf5, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

To press ok.  However when I try to navigate again, I'll get an error that the webbrowser is still busy.  How can I force it to become free again?

The only workaround I have found is to try to "restart" the browser.  I am doing the following:

```
ie.Dispose();
ie = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
```

This seems to work, but as soon as I navigate, I get a "A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly" popup.  I can still continue navigating but I notice that overtime I have a rather large memory leak.  I'm not sure if it is from the way I have "restarting" the browser or from leaving the popup up.

If you have a way to "free" the browser or if you can confirm the correct way to restart a browser, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does 0xf5 do? And do you have a valid handle to the OK button?

Comment: Yes, I am able to press the OK button and the popup goes away.

Comment: Perhaps its a buggy webpage?  Seen alot of those....  Can you focus on 'known' web pages that seem to be OK ...and see what happens?

Comment: perhaps, but my program should be resilient to buggy webpages.  That is why I ask if there is a way to force the browser to stop being "busy" so I can navigate.  Or, if you can confirm if I am properly restarting the browser

Answer (score 0):

It certainly seems that you are using `Dispose()` correctly to destroy (elegantly) the WebBrowser class.  And creating it with `new` is fine also.  (Just take care of which thread you use - as per link below)

According to [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx), you could try a `Stop()` and `Refresh()` sequence, although this may not prevent the memory leak.

It's hard to tell from your scant code if the leak is due to the Browser class, your code or the webpages themselves...(Most likely the web pages, considering the amount of buggy webpages)

But if speed is not important, disposing and renewing the WebBrowser class should not be an issue

Comment: I have tried Stop and Refresh but it does not seem to clear the "busy" status.

As for using dispose to restart the browser I don't think it is really doing that.  I use dispose() then wait 30min, then re-create the browser and navigate.  As soon as this happens I get the "A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly" popup.  I can only assume that something in the browser remained and it thinks a script was running for 30min

Comment: Is this all happening on one particular web page?  What happens if you browse normally to that web page (in a browser like Firefox, Chrome...) and use the developer tools to see if there are errors in the web page.

Comment: Have you checked the advanced Internet Options in your Control Panel - that governs IE - and see what the configuration is when script errors occur?  If you don't know what I mean, let me know - I will add a picture